# Leaking double submit cookie through form request before attack?

Tags: security, csrf, websecurity

From what I understand, when a user visits a site, the site can give a double submit token as a cookie and as a form value. When the user submits a form, the site checks for the token in the form values and in the cookies. If the double submit token in the cookies matches the token in the form value, then the form request is valid. Since the attacker cannot access the double submit token through the cookie, the attacker does not know the valid token to send along with the form, and the form is rejected.

My question is why can't the attacker get the token by requesting the form before the attack? For example:

1. User visits attacker.com
2. attacker.com sends a GET request through User's browser to get the form from vulnerable.com
3. vulnerable.com sets the double submit token in the User's cookies, and also returns the token as part of the form back to attacker.com
4. attacker.com takes the double submit token from the form, and then crafts a malicious form with the token. Since the malicious form has the correct double submit token, the malicious form is accepted by vulnerable.com

Is my understanding of double submit cookies flawed (e.g. the client is supposed add the double submit token to the form, not the server)? Or is there some implementation detail I'm missing (e.g. some policy to set to prevent attackers from getting the form beforehand)?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is unique to the session, so the cookie sent to  the attacker will be different from the cookie sent to (and expected from) the user.

Comment: I'm confused on a few parts. If the attacker is acting through the user's browser, then doesn't that mean the server can't tell the difference between the attacker and the user, and so cannot send the right user cookie or attacker cookie? Also, aren't Double Submit cookies designed to be stateless, and do not have a way to be tied to session?

Comment: @BaconErie, perhaps what you are missing is the standard attacker threat model.  An attacker might be able to get the victim's browser to visit any URL of the attacker's choice (e.g., by sending a phishing email with a link, or running an ad, etc.), but the attacker won't be able to see the server's response or the cookies sent by the server in response.  The web server uses sessions to keep track of sessions -- I suggest reading about session cookies and sessions, and reading some basic material on web security. The Tangled Web is a great book for that.

Comment: @BaconErie, https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65854195/781723